# Designing code for accessing a WebService that accepts xml requests

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I'd like to create C# code that accesses a WebService that has only 1 method:

```
public string HandleRequest(string xml).
```

The request itself is sent in xml, where the xml content specifies which type of action to perform and required/optional parameters as well.

The response from the service is also returned in xml and may be different per each request type that is sent.

I'd like to design a solution that will facilitate interacting with this service, and that will allow me to:

1. Dynamically generate an xml from given parameters (action type, other optional args, etc). Currently the xml is loaded from a file that was already created
2. Parse the response in an easy way (creating a strongly typed object from it?)

What's a good solution for doing this? I find it hard to come up with one, as the request/response xml is dynamic and may change from call to call.

Some additional info:

1. The service is Java based and is hosted under Tomcat (Axis 1.2)
2. There's no wsdl document for the service (even if there was, i wouldn't be able to automatically generate some strongly typed request/response classes, as the service itself receives and outputs only XML and not some complex type).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an XML-RPC implementation could be what you are after. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC);

> XML-RPC works by sending a HTTP request to a server implementing the
>   protocol. The client in that case is typically software wanting to
>   call a **single method** of a remote system. Multiple input parameters can
>   be passed to the remote method, one return value is returned. The
>   parameter types allow nesting of parameters into maps and lists, thus
>   larger structures can be transported. Therefore XML-RPC can be used to
>   transport objects or structures both as input and as output
>   parameters.

Wikipedia also lists some [Java Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Java) of this protocol.

While, I've not used this specifically, I've worked with a service designed around a bastardised version of [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification). As it didn't follow the spec truely, we couldn't utilise any pre-existing implementations.

Personally, I didn't see the benefit of using such a protocol as we still needed to have clear definitions of the operations exposed by the service along with their associated constraints such as mandatory parameters etc. In addition to that, we had to handle the serialisation/deserialisation of JSON (XML in your case) to the associated object model. This was largely due to the vendor we were interacting with and their lack of conformance to the spec. If yours is conformant, then you may find that the existing implementations provided might give you a neat way of handling this.

Note the critisims regarding bloat of XML-RPC on Wikipedia too. It might pay to look into JSON-RPC as an alternative. There are certainly a few [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations) listed that you can check out.

**Edit:** I didn't read your question properly. Sorry. I thought you were looking at **providing** a service. I'd still look at the links around XML-RPC/JSON-RPC as it may give you an idea as to how to knock up a test client. As far as .NET goes, I looked at the [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) codebase to get an idea of how the JSON-RPC protocol was implemented and if we could have used that in our scenario. You can get a rough idea as to how they handle the requests and responses. From memory, they may even have a test harness or sample code showing how to call the service. That could give you some ideas.